# What sparse solver supports diagonal storage format

Tags: c, sparse-matrix, intel-mkl

I'm writing finite-difference method program using C. The stiffness matrix is symmetrical and band. For its storage I'd like to use Sparse Diagonal Storage format.

Could someone tell please, what solvers can use diagonal storage format? Intel MKL's Paradiso uses only CRS-format, SparseLib doesn't have, Spooles seems also =(

Thank you.

Comment: I've offered an answer [here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/5618/3907) on your SciComp SE post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sparse libraries concentrate on general purpose sparse storage. For banded matrices you can use any of the standard linear algebra libraries, for example LAPACK.